# Binding images in DevExpress Gridview

Tags: devexpress

I am working in DevExpress Gridview Concepts. I am new to this. My requirement is, i should display the image in the gridview. There will more than one image, if so, it should be binded in the second row. I will get the image path from the database.

Kindly provide me the sample code. I had searched google a lot, but i cant able to find this particular scenario.

In the following link, i had given my source code part..

http://community.devexpress.com/forums/p/105855/358119.aspx#358119

Comment: What platform you are interested in?

Comment: I am working in .Net and SQL Server. In that i am using DevExpress Gridview..

Comment: which one DevExpress GridView? ASP.NET, WinForms, WPF, SL, VCL?

Comment: Kindly go through this link...http://community.devexpress.com/forums/p/105855/358119.aspx#358119

Comment: In this link, i had given my source code part..

Comment: thanks, it looks like the WinForms XtraGrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it different ways .......

```
public class MyClass
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public byte[] MyImage { get; set; }
}
```

which is a wrapper class for a table storing images as binary blobs (MS SQL image or varbinary(max), Oracle BLOB etc.)

I found 4 different ways (that is, “simple ways”; certainly there are countless other more complex alternatives) to display the binary data as images, using DevExpress’ [ASPxImage](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxEditorsASPxImagetopic) and [ASPxBinaryImage](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxEditorsASPxBinaryImagetopic) controls inside a [ASPxGridView](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridViewtopic):

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="gridImages" runat="server"
  AutoGenerateColumns="False" KeyFieldName="ID">
  <Columns>
    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="ID" FieldName="ID">
    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```

using a query like

```
var images = database.Query<MyImages>().OrderBy(r => r.ID);
gridImages.DataSource = images;
gridImages.DataBind();
```

Using [GridViewDataBinaryImageColumn](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxGridViewGridViewDataBinaryImageColumntopic)

```
    <dx:GridViewDataBinaryImageColumn FieldName="MyImage">
    </dx:GridViewDataBinaryImageColumn>
```

**Using ASPxBinaryImage inside a DataItemTemplate**

```
 <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="MyImage" >
      <DataItemTemplate>
        <dx:ASPxBinaryImage ID="img" runat="server"
          Value='<%# Eval("MyImage") %>'>
        </dx:ASPxBinaryImage>
      </DataItemTemplate>
    </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
```

ASPxBinaryImage uses the Value property to store a byte array, which the DevExpress framework translates into  where src requests a DevExpress-implemented URL to serve the byte stream.

If you prefer ASP:Image or ASPxImage to ASPxBinaryImage, you need to write an .ashx handler to retrieve the image data:

```
public class MyImageHandler : IHttpHandler
{
  public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
  {
    int id = 0;
    int.TryParse(context.Request["id"], out id);

    var image = database.FirstOrDefault<MyClass>(c => c.ID == id);

    if (image == null)
    {
      context.Response.Clear();
      return;
    }

    context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(image.MyImage);
    context.Response.End();
  }
```

This .ashx handler is invoked by setting the ImageUrlFormatString of a [GridViewDataImageColumn](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxGridViewGridViewDataImageColumntopic)

or by **setting the ImageUrl property of an ASPxImage:**

```
 <dx:GridViewDataColumn >
      <DataItemTemplate>
        <dx:ASPxImage runat="server" ID="imgTemplate"
          ImageUrl='<%#  "myimage.ashx?id=" + Eval("ID")  %>'>
        </dx:ASPxImage>
      </DataItemTemplate>
    </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
  </Columns>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you searched the DevExpress Support Center.  There are pages of examples here:

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/SearchResults.aspx#cD1UNHxQMXw1NnNlYXJjaHRleHQ9SW1hZ2UgaW4gZ3JpZHZpZXc=

Comment: I cant able to open this link..

Comment: Go to the devexpress support center at devexpress.com/support/center and type search on image in gridview.  Make sure to review the tabs for questions and knowlegebase articles.  If that doesn't answer your question, then the support center is by far the best place to get your question answered.

Answer (score 0):

The following KB article describes how to accomplish this task:
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/p/A2707.aspx

It describes the main idea and contains an example, which can be downloaded

Comment: i had already tried that example. Its not fulfils my requirement